# Is the dual of a reflexive Banach space strictly convex?

Tags: banach-spaces, approximation-theory, finite-element-method

Is the dual of a reflexive Banach space strictly convex? Why?

This is a question that arouse trying to understand the theory behind approximation by finite element methods.

Comment: At best, it would have a strictly convex equivalent norm. Otherwise, for a counterexample take any finite dimensional, non-strictly convex space. (E.g., $\mathbb{R^2}$ with $L^\infty$ norm.)

Comment: Also, “dual of a reflexive Banach space” is just a difficult way of saying “reflexive Banach space” …

Comment: These are valid remarks. I would settle for a strictly convex equivalent norm.

Comment: See [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CFEQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Fbull%2F1966-72-06%2FS0002-9904-1966-11606-3%2FS0002-9904-1966-11606-3.pdf&ei=zzDUUoy7AeehsQTU-IGIDA&usg=AFQjCNEOtOhcw3TT0P8ngFPW5pe1_HRcdw&bvm=bv.59026428,d.cWc&cad=rja).

Comment: Very interesting, thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Joram Lindenstrauss has shown that a reflexive Banach space admits a strictly convex equivalent norm.  The paper in which this result appears (as Corollary 1) can be freely downloaded from [this page](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183528494).  ([This paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC8QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fpublication%2F31268486_Strictly_convex_renormings%2Ffile%2Fe0b4951de7bee4e185.pdf&ei=NzbUUryLI5LgsASukoDgCw&usg=AFQjCNF9WzSeHLmz_Pb-8rHuNtpLacnkuw&bvm=bv.59026428,d.cWc&cad=rja) also seems relevant; in fact, the results mentioned in the first paragraph show how Corollary 1 of the Lindenstrauss paper follows from Theorem 1).

It is worth pointing out that it's relatively easy to show that a separable Banach space admits a strictly convex norm (and smooth as well).  The proof of this can be found on page 33 of W. B. Johnson and J. Lindenstrauss' article in the *Handbook of the Geometry of Banach Spaces*, Vol 1. (The  paper mentioned in the first paragraph  in part aimed to show that this result holds for reflexive non-separable spaces.)

Comment: Any hope for a canonical choice of the equivalent strictly convex norm?